# Scheme: List All the Ways to Make Change for 10 Using a List

Tags: scheme

**Goal:** total: 10
          denoms: (10 5 1)
          return ((10) (5 5) (5 1 1 1 1 1) (1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1))

My code:

```
(define (changes-list total denoms)

    (cond

    ((null? denoms) nil )

    ((= total 0 ))

    ((> (car denoms) total) (changes-list total (cdr denoms)))

    (else

      (if (= total (car denoms)) (cons (list (car denoms)) (changes-list total (cdr denoms)))
      (append (cons-all (car denoms) (changes-list (- total (car denoms)) denoms))))
    )  )  )
```

~~~~~~
What my code outputs right now is: ((10) (5 5) (5 1 1 1 1 1))
I think the problem may lie in cond if, when I call changes-list on (cdr denoms) and that changes denoms to an empty and exits but I do not know how to fix this. All help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: There are two cases which you need to join together: using `(car denoms)`, and not using `(car denoms)`. You're only doing the former.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following two conditions (otherwise you should check the parameters):

1. `total` is always non-negative,
2. `denoms` is sorted in decreasing order and the last element is always `1`,

here is a possible solution:

```
(define (cons-all x lst)
  (map (lambda (l) (cons x l)) lst))

(define (repeat n x)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons x (repeat (- n 1) x))))

(define (changes-list total denoms)
  (cond ((= total 0) '(()))
        ((null? (cdr denoms)) (list (repeat total (car denoms))))
        ((< total (car denoms)) (changes-list total (cdr denoms)))
        (else (append (cons-all (car denoms) (changes-list (- total (car denoms)) denoms))
                      (changes-list total (cdr denoms))))))

(changes-list '6 (2 1)) ; => ((2 2 2) (2 2 1 1) (2 1 1 1 1) (1 1 1 1 1 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying different paths of which not everyone will yield a valid solution I like to use an `path` list to keep track of the path, and an accumulator `acc` to only keep the successful results:

```
(define (changes-list total denoms)
  (let iter ((total total) (denoms denoms) (path '()) (acc '()))
    (cond
      ((= total 0) (cons (reverse path) acc)) ; the current path lead to a solution => keep path in accumulator
      ((or (< total 0) (null? denoms)) acc) ; discard path
      (else
       (let ((denom (car denoms))) ; first denomination
         (iter (- total denom)     ; (1) use first denomination
               denoms
               (cons denom path)
               (iter total         ; (2) drop first denomination
                     (cdr denoms)
                     path
                     acc)))))))
```

Testing:

```
> (changes-list 10 '(10 5 1))
'((10) (5 5) (5 1 1 1 1 1) (1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1))
> (changes-list 6 '(2 1))
'((2 2 2) (2 2 1 1) (2 1 1 1 1) (1 1 1 1 1 1))
```